# How to provide a fallback CSS-value within a custom element?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, custom-element, css-variables

I have a custom web-component which is basically an SVG-Icon:

```
<custom-icon>
    <svg>{svg-stuff}</svg>
</custom-icon>
```

I want to be able to change it's size by applying CSS like so:

```
custom-icon {
    width: 20px;
}
```

But I also would like to have a fallback default value when no CSS is applied. However, when I inline some CSS like `<custom-icon style="width:15px">` it just overwrites all CSS I apply afterwards. How can I have the default "15px" only apply if there is no custom CSS?

MWE:

```js
class CustomIcon extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    let size = "100px"
    
    this.style.height = size;
    this.style.width = size;
    
    this.style.background = "firebrick"
    this.style.display = "block"
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-icon', CustomIcon);
```

```css
custom-icon {
  --icon-size: 50px;
  height: var(--icon-size);
  width: var(--icon-size);
}
```

```html
<custom-icon />
```

Comment: Add a class to your component like this <custom-icon class="custom-icon">...</custom-icon> and change CSS tag declaration to class one: custom-icon { => .custom-class { width: 15px; }

Comment: `have a fallback default value when no CSS is applied` what do you mean by that? why should the css not be applied?

Comment: if you have an inline style your css must use `!important` - it's the only way to override inline styles - but be careful when using it as it can become a specificity nightmare

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov Could you modify the snippet accordingly? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @Pete I'd like to avoid that if possible

Comment: @Thomas Imagine this icon-element being used in many instances. Some might want it in a specific size and will declare this in the CSS. Most, however, will use the default size and will therefore not apply any CSS.

Comment: Then I guess the way to do it would be to have your bare selector as your default value, then add a class for your overrides

Comment: @Pete, could you elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content of your custom element is encapsulated in a Shadow DOM, which is a recommended practice, you can use the `:host` pseudo-class to define a default style.

Then if you define a global style for your custom element it will override the one defined with `:host`.

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-icon', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    let size = 100
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = `
          <style>
            :host {
               display: inline-block ;
               height: ${size}px ;
               width: ${size}px ;
               background-color: firebrick ; 
               color: white;
            }
          </style>
          <slot></slot>`
  }
} )
```

```css
custom-icon#i1 {
  --icon-size: 50px;
  height: var(--icon-size);
  width: var(--icon-size);
}
```

```html
<custom-icon id="i1">sized</custom-icon>
<hr>
<custom-icon>default</custom-icon>
```

Comment: I know that. It just doesn't make sense inside a Minimal(!)WE. So, thanks for the tip but that doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: @leonheess actually it does. See the added example.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Now that I got your approach, it's actually pretty helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The order is applied according to [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade).

CSS applied via the `style` attribute is at the bottom of the cascade. In effect, if you *don't* specify via the attribute when it falls back to the stylesheet.

So `20px` is the fallback for when you don't specify `15px`.

---

You could write your fallback CSS using another rule-set with a **less specific** selector (although the only thing less specific than a single type selector (like `custom-icon`) is the universal selector (`*`) which isn't helpful) so you would need to replace `custom-icon` with something *more* specific.

The other option is the take the sledgehammer approach and make every rule in your ruleset `!important`.

---

The best option would probably be to fix whatever circumstance might cause your CSS to be missing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider data attribute and then use that attribute as a fallback for the custom property.

You can see in the below, that the size will have no effect until we remove the custom property (by setting `initial`)

```js
class CustomIcon extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.style.height = `var(--icon-size, ${this.getAttribute('size')})`;
    this.style.width = `var(--icon-size, ${this.getAttribute('size')})`;
    
    this.style.background = "firebrick"
    this.style.display = "block"
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-icon', CustomIcon);
```

```css
custom-icon {
  --icon-size: 50px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<custom-icon size="15px"></custom-icon>
<custom-icon size="25px"></custom-icon>
<custom-icon size="2050px"></custom-icon>


<custom-icon size="200px" style="--icon-size:initial"></custom-icon>
```

Related question to understand the use of `initial` : [CSS custom properties (variables) for box model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55615332/8620333)

Another example where the custom property is not set initially.

```js
class CustomIcon extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.style.height = `var(--icon-size, ${this.getAttribute('size')})`;
    this.style.width = `var(--icon-size, ${this.getAttribute('size')})`;

    this.style.background = "firebrick"
    this.style.display = "block"
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-icon', CustomIcon);
```

```css
custom-icon {
  margin: 5px;
}

.set {
  --icon-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="set">
  <custom-icon size="15px"></custom-icon>
  <custom-icon size="25px"></custom-icon>
  <custom-icon size="2050px"></custom-icon>
</div>

<custom-icon size="200px" ></custom-icon>
```

Comment: @leonheess here is some related Answers to get more *powerful* things around CSS variables and their fallback: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53239880/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Comment: In custom elements, *read access* on attributes **is not allowed in the `constructor`**. It disallows for dynamical creation of the element using `new CustomIcon` or `document.createElement('custom-icon')`. Also you call them *data attribute*   - that term is reserved for `data-` prefixed attributes.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance **Requirements for custom element constructors and reactions** [...] *The element's attributes and children must not be inspected, as in the non-upgrade case none will be present, and relying on upgrades makes the element less usable.*

Comment: @connexo What do you recommend instead?