# Inherit a CSS variable, or fallback to default

Tags: css, css-variables

Say I am a library author of some web component; I want to allow the user to set the background color of my component. I allow this by setting `--background-color`. For example, the user can code:

```
:root {
  --background-color: green;
}
```

Now in my component, I want to either take the user's value for `--background-color`, or use a default color:

```
.some-component {
  display: contents;
  --background-color: var(--background-color, red);
}
```

The code above however doesn't work. I don't mind, there are workarounds; but I would like to know *why* it doesn't work, if anyone has an answer for that.

In the code below, green is expected, but the line `--background-color: var(--background-color, red);` seems to "break" somehow the CSS.

```css
:root {
  --background-color: green;
}
.some-component {
  display: contents;
  --background-color: var(--background-color, red); /* this doesn't work */
}
.some-component__container {
  background-color: var(--background-color, blue);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- user code -->
<div class="app">
  <!-- library code -->
  <div class="some-component">
    <div class="some-component__container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to override the variable with itself, which is not going to work. You could perhaps define a `--fallback-bg` value instead? `background-color: var(--background-color, var(--fallback-bg));`

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Actually I like your approach. You can make an answer, and I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to help.

Comment: The first duplicate will give you the *why* and here another related question giving almost the same idea as the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60660908/8620333 (the JS is irrelevant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't override a variable with itself, so what I can suggest is to define a second variable that will contain your fallback value for each context:

```css
:root {
  --fallback-bg: green;
}
.some-component {
  display: contents;
  --fallback-bg: red;
}
.some-component__container {
  background-color: var(--background-color, var(--fallback-bg));
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

You can also define a fallback for your fallback if you'd like:
`background-color: var(--background-color, var(--fallback-bg, green));`

Comment: thanks, in `:root` should be `--background-color: green;`