# css variable - default value on var not getting passed

Tags: css, css-grid, css-variables

I get 2 different output for the code below. It should give the same output since default value should be taken by the css variable. Below is the code where I commented passing `span` a value, since it has a default value in the var declaration . Uncommenting the value assignment line give different output. Looking for a explanation of what is happening.

Here is the code pen with commented code - https://codepen.io/skandasoft/pen/MWjoMZe

and here is with uncommented - https://codepen.io/skandasoft/pen/VwKWJqd

Bootstrappy Grid with CSS Variables!

```
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item" style="--span: 7">
            <div class="grid" style="--cols: 2">
                <div class="item">1</div>
                <div class="item">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>

    <style>
        .grid {
            display: grid;
            gap: 10px;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols, 10), minmax(0, 1fr));
        }
        .item {
            /* --span: 1; */
            grid-column: span var(--span, 1); /**-span has a default value of 1 **/
            background-color: yellow;
            padding:10px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom properties inherit.

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#syntax):

> Custom properties are ordinary properties, so they can be declared on
> any element, are resolved with the **normal inheritance** and cascade
> rules, ...

This means that if no value is set for a custom property on a given element, the value of its parent is used.

In this case, the parent element defines the custom property:  `--span`:

```
<div class="item" style="--span: 7">
```

So the value of the --span property will be 7 on all the children - unless a different value is explicitly defined on a child.

Now the difference between the two versions of the code is clear.

In the commented version, `var(--span, 1)` in the .item class evaluates to 7 due to inheritance

Since there are only 2 columns in the grid, each item spans the full grid width

In the uncommented version (with `--span: 1`; defined in the .item class), `var(--span, 1)` in the .item class evaluates to 1 - because it is explicitly defined on the child.

### NB

Fallback values are only used as the substitution value when a given custom property is invalid / not defined

In this case, the second item in the outer grid defines the --span custom property with value 7 and it is available to all its child elements.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `.item` class has a higher specificity than the inherited `--span: 7` that was provided. See the below screenshot of it being overriden. So if you set `--span: 7` on these 2 child elements (1 & 2), you will no longer see a difference toggling the `--span: 1` value on and off.

As far as I can tell, the default values are correctly set.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @Danield the issue is inheritance and you can avoid it by using `initial` like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols, 10), minmax(0, 1fr));
  --span:initial; /* this will stop the propagation of the variable */
}

.item {
  grid-column: span var(--span, 1); /**-span has a default value of 1 **/
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item" style="--span: 7">
    <div class="grid" style="--cols: 2">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Related questions:

[CSS custom properties (variables) for box model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55615332/8620333)

[How to store inherit value inside a CSS variable (aka custom property)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53239880/8620333)

Comment: explicit Initial to avoid this inheritance is a good idea