# Using a CSS variable inside @if in Scss

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

During the creation of styles, I had an idea of creating a CSS variable that represents the boolean value to display or not the transparency but I saw that the condition, unfortunately, does not work!

main.css

```
:root {
    --navbar-transparent: "true";
  }
```

navbar.component.scss

```
@if var(--navbar-transparent) == "true" {
.nav-booking {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
} @else {
.nav-booking{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d6d1d180;
 }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with CSS variables? Or is it impossible?

Comment: it's impossible ... CSS variable are evaluated at run time and doesn't exist in SASS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes unfortunately, but we are trying to look for an alternative

Answer (score 3):

You can *hack* an `if() {}` like below but I doubt you can do an `if() {} else {}`

```css
* {
  --navbar-transparent: true;
  
}

.nav-booking {
    /* if !true */
    padding:var(--navbar-transparent,20px);
    border:var(--navbar-transparent,5px solid green);
    /*  */
    
    background:red;
    height:10px;
    margin:10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="nav-booking" ></div>

<!-- you need to set "initial" to get your false -->
<div class="nav-booking" style="--navbar-transparent:initial"></div>
```

Related to get mode detail around the use of `initial`

[How to store inherit value inside a CSS variable (aka custom property)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53239880/8620333)

[CSS custom properties (variables) for box model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55615332/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

In sass custom-properties are unfortunately just treated as a string, it doesn't associat a value.

However there are workarounds:

```
@function get($var) {
  @return map-get($custom-properties, $var);
}

$custom-properties: ();

@each $key, $value in $custom-properties {
  :root {
    --#{$key}: #{$value};
  }
}
```

Add any variable, you want to use within your Sass project and also be compiled to a custom-property, to this map: `$custom-properties: ();`.

```
$custom-properties: (
  'navbar-transparent': true,
  //...
);
```

Now use `get($var)` to acces said variables within your Sass project.

```
@function get($var) {
  @return map-get($custom-properties, $var);
}

$custom-properties: (
  'navbar-transparent': true,
);

@each $key, $value in $custom-properties {
  :root {
    --#{$key}: #{$value};
  }
}

@if (get(navbar-transparent)) {
  .nav-booking {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
} @else {
  .nav-booking{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d6d1d180;
  }
}
```

This will compile to:

```
:root {
  --navbar-transparent: true;
}

.nav-booking {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/LudwigGeorgImmanuel/pen/dypaXyE

Comment: I appreciate your very detailed answer, but we need to control the boolean from css file *main.css* exactly in :root {}, with your solution we will be obliged to control it from scss variable.

Comment: @SalahEddineBentayeb. Then you're stuck with Javascript, no way to achieve this with pure Sass.